# App Showing Encrypted data in Xcode Simulator but not in TestFlight

Tags: ios, xcode, encryption, aes, testflight

I have an app which is using AES encryption to store user data.
Have got ITSEncryptionExportComplianceCode approval and code as well.
And have added it in info.plist as well.
When i run the application in Xcode simulator or on device in debug mode, app does show the encrypted data when fetched from local database.
But when i push the same build to testFlight and then download and use from there then the app does not the show the encrypted data.

Answer (score 0):

I believe in the process of releasing the app to TestFlight, Apple asks you if you are using any encryption, so you should check that.

Comment: Did that still not visible

Comment: Does it work when you just archive the app, export it, and then install the IPA via Xcode on the iPhone?

Comment: For Development build it is working but for distribution build , on TestFlight not working